# Laravel updating database route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to update a column in my database with a total of votes on a project. I'm having a 404 problem but I don't see the problem in my route. (PS: Laravel 3)

This is my Vote button on every project :

```
{{ Form::open('project/addvote', 'VOTE') }}
{{ Form::hidden('id', $project->id) }}
{{ Form::submit('Vote') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So when you click on the vote button it use this route :

```
Route::put('project/addvote', array('uses'=>'projects@addvote'));
```

And this is my action in the projects controller (no updating yet, just trying to redirect) :

```
public function put_addvote(){
        return Redirect::to_route('project', $id)
        ->with('message', 'Vote successful');
}
```

Redirecting to this route :

```
Route::get('project/(:num)', array('as'=>'project', 'uses'=>'projects@project'));
```

And this is getting me the 404 error

Thanks to every response and the great help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Actually, `Redirect::to_route` expects a name of a route to redirect to it and a named route has to be declare with a name, like,</del>

<del>Route::put('project/addvote', array('as' => 'project',  'uses'=>'projects@addvote'));</del>

<del>So, you can use it;s name to redirect to it like</del>

<del>return Redirect::to_route('project');</del>
<del>Here, `project` has been used as it's name using `'as' => 'project'`. In, your example, you didn't gave any name to the route, here</del>

<del>Route::put('project/addvote', array('uses'=>'projects@addvote'));</del>
<del>The, `as => 'route_name'` is missing.</del>

For second question, you can do it as

```
$id = Input::get('id');
Project::find($id);
Project->votenumber = 5;
Project->->save();
```

[**Inserting & Updating Models**](http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#save).

### Update :

It was a bit confusing but after a conversation through the commenting system the answer for routing is give below :

You (OP) mentioned that you have a route declared as

```
 Route::get('projets', array('as'=>'projets', 'uses'=>'projets@index'));
```

To this route you are trying to redirect using this

```
return Redirect::to_route('project', $id);
```

So, you are passing a parameter and it's not in your route declaration and this is the problem, so to overcome this change your route declaration to this

```
Route::get('projets/(:num)', array('as'=>'projets', 'uses'=>'projets@index'));
```

Or

```
Route::get('projets/(:any)', array('as'=>'projets', 'uses'=>'projets@index'));
```

Or, you can make the param optional using a `?`, for example :

```
Route::get('projets/(:any?)', array('as'=>'projets', 'uses'=>'projets@index'));
```

[**Check wildcard Routes**](http://three.laravel.com/docs/routing#wildcards).

### Update :

<del>You should have postd the original code with the question, anyways,</del> Change this

```
return Redirect::to_route('project', $id);
```

to

```
return Redirect::to_route('project', array($id));
```

Comment: No I actually had the redirect route. Route::get('projets', array('as'=>'projets', 'uses'=>'projets@index')); So I have still the same problem

Comment: In your question you posted the route as `Route::put('project/addvote', array('uses'=>'projects@addvote'));` maybe you should update your question with exact route and code.

Comment: That's the route for when I press a "Vote" button, sending to this routing that is starting the addVote function. Then, the addVote function redirects back to the projects menu with the route I just showed. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Got it but you passed an id like `$id`, did you mentioned it in your route ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't give the good route. I will edit main question so it is more clear

Comment: Edited main question, the route with /(:any) existed

Comment: I can't believe that was the error... Sorry for the trouble. and thanks a lot for your sustain help! I'll try to search more docs online before asking more laravel questions

Comment: You are welcome and [three.laravel.com/docs](http://three.laravel.com/docs) is the doc for Laravel-3 and try Laravel-4 for new projects.

Comment: Oh that will be helpful thank you. And yes this is the right answer